# Can any quaternion be written in exponential form?

Tags: quaternions

I am new to the topic of quaternions, but I have an excellent understanding of complex numbers and linear algebra.

I read that unitary quaternions (or *versors*) can be written in the form:
$q = \exp(a\textbf{r}) = \cos(a) + \textbf{r}\sin(a)~,$ where $r^2 = -1$ and has no real part. This is similar to the complex formalism that is: $c = A \exp(i\theta) = A[cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)]$.

Can any quaternion be written in the same manner, by extending the formulation to:
$q = A\exp(a\textbf{r}) = A[\cos(a) + \textbf{r}\sin(a)]$ ? If so, does the multiplication still work the same?

I have been trying to perform a quaternion rotation described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) by hand, but I'm puzzeled by how to handle commutativity...

Comment: Certainly any quaternion can be written $q=Aexp(ar)$ where $r^2=-1$. I am not sure I understand what does it mean "the multiplication still work the same".

Comment: Look at: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17264/why-dont-quaternions-have-an-overall-phase/110224#110224

Comment: @semyonalesker If quaternions can be written that way, then multiplying $q_1=A_1\exp(a_1 r_1)$ and $q_2$ (defined the same) into $q_1\cdot q_2 = A_1 A_2 exp(a_1 r_1 + a_2 r_2)$. Same thing if I multiply three quaternions. Then, any rotation operation defined with $p' = qpq^{-1}$ would be equal to $p$ (because arguments inside the exponential would simply cancel themselves).

Comment: After a quick examination, maybe this should have been posted on math.stackoverflow. I didn't know these were different sites...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication ... Note
$$
\exp(a_1\textbf{r}_1) \exp(a_2\textbf{r}_2)= \exp(a_1\textbf{r}_1+a_2\textbf{r}_2) 
$$
provided $\textbf{r}_1$ and $\textbf{r}_2$ commute, which is not always true.